# How to use short path when writing a file

Tags: java, path, filewriter

When I getting something in my code I use a short path like

```
this.getStylesheets().add("/css/editorTool.css");
```

but when I writing a new file I give exact paht - like:

```
File f = new File("D:\\IdeaProjects\\SmartCRM for TB\\EditorTool\\resourses\\html\\test.html");
    try{
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            bw.write(html);
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As i will have to distribute this app among some users I will not be able to garanty that the absolute path to my app will be the same. How i can write it to so that it is like "path_to_the_folder_that_is_contained_in_app + fileName?

Comment: Use a [relative path](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)? If your app directory is for example `EditorTool` then you can just use the path `"resourses\\html\\test.html"`

Comment: This does not work - gives an exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resourses\html\test.html
May be this is because I use Intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use system property **"user.dir"** to get current working path, the code is alike this:

```
String currentWorkingPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String fullPath = currentWorkingPath  + File.separator+ fileName;
```

then the file will be under currentWorkingPath when the program run on any PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getResource()` method of `java.lang.Class<T>`

> The java.lang.Class.getResource() finds a resource with a given name

[Documentation Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

usage:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("html/test.html").getPath());
```